# Python 3 "IndexError: pop index out of range"

Tags: python, index-error

I have been asked to model the monty hall problem for my computer science homework. It was going rather well, until i got he error `IndexError: pop index out of range`. I know my code is probably rather sloppy and horrible for all you actual programmers out there, so I'm sorry if you have a hard time making sense of this. I am only looking for solutions for the index error, and please try to not make them too complicated- this is the first time I have used python after 6 months off of school. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import random
import time
wins_switch = 0
losses_switch = 0
total_switch = 0
wins_stick = 0
losses_stick = 0
total_stick = 0

      
#while True : 
print ("Monty hall problem model")
global doors
doors = [0, 0, 1]
which = random.randint(0,2)
print ("This is the door that has been chosen: " +(str(which)))
stick_or_switch = random.randint(0,1)
if which == 0:
      doors.pop(1)
      print("Door 1 has been removed")
      print (doors)
      if stick_or_switch == 0:
            print("The computer has decided to stick with door 0")
            print("Therefore, that is a loss")
            doors.pop(2)
            losses_stick =+1
            print(doors)
      else:
            print("The computer has decided to switch")
            print("Therefore that is a win")
            doors.pop(0)
            wins_switch = +1
            print(doors)
elif which == 1:
      doors.pop(0)
      print ("Door 0 has been removed")
      print(doors)
      if stick_or_switch == 0:
            print("The computer has decided to stick with door 1")
            print("Therefore, that is a loss")
            doors.pop(2)
            losses_stick =+1
            print(doors)
      else:
            print("The computer has decided to switch to door ")
            print("Therefore that is a win")
            doors.pop(2)
            wins_switch = +1
            print(doors)
else:
      random_door = random.randint(0,1)
      doors.pop(random_door)
      print ("Door " + str(random_door) + " has been removed")
      if random_door == 0:
            if stick_or_switch == 0:
                  print("The computer had decided to stick with door 2")
                  print("Therefore, that is a win")
                  doors.pop(1)
                  wins_stick=+1
                  print(doors)
            else:
                  print("The computer has decided to switch")
                  print("Therefore that is a loss")
                  doors.pop(2)
                  losses_switch =+1
                  print(doors)
      else:
            if stick_or_switch == 0:
                  print("The computer has decided to stick with door 2 ")
                  print("Therefore, that is a win")
                  doors.pop(0)
                  wins_stick=+1
                  print(doors)
            else:
                  print("The computer has decided to switch")
                  print("Therefore that is a loss")
                  doors.pop(2)
                  losses_switch =+1
                  print(doors)
            
            
      print (doors)
```

Comment: Please look at how to create a [mre]. You can't just throw all your code here without even posting the actual error and expect people to help you. Find out what the problem is, and post the shortest code necessary to re-create it. You can also have a look at [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Welcome to SO mate. Don’t worry we all were there. However can you please indicate at which line of code you got above error.

Comment: I would imagine this is being caused by trying to do `doors.pop(2)` after already doing `doors.pop(1)`

Comment: Yes , it would be ethically wrong to give complete solutions. But after reading your code I can identify your issue. As @7koFnMiP has mentioned , once you did pop(1) , your list length reduced to 2, now python followed 0 based indexing , pop(2) is throwing out of index exception.

Comment: thank you @rahulrai for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the line number where the error occurs... It will give you hints.

Looking at your code what happens (most likely) is that you "pop" a door out, thus you have only 2 doors left, and then I guess, you try to pop the third door (whose index is `2`, i.e. you use `.pop(2)`) and you get this error because you have only two doors left so there is no such third door.

Comment: If your answer includes 'most likely' then you should probably add a comment to clarify instead